# Способы проверки наличия свойства объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты

В чём принципиальная разница между разными способами проверки наличия свойства в объекте\массиве `JS`? Может есть разница в производительности или вопрос только в личных предпочтениях программиста?

Приведу примеры таких проверок, он далеко не полный, только те, с которыми мне приходилось сталкиваться:

```
if (key in obj){
   //code
}

if (obj.hasOwnProperty('key')){
   //code
}

if (typeof obj['key'] !== "undefined") {
   //code
}
```

и даже такой:

```
if(Object.keys(obj).includes('key')){
   //code
}
```

Comment: Моё мнение. что это не просто вопрос предпочтений, а именно вопрос производительности, каждое действие которое Вы вызываете в js (да и в других языках), выполняет определённые инструкции процессора и задействуют память (зачастую) чем меньше будет этих инструкций тем быстрее будет выполняться программа, так что вызовы функций зачастую требуют больше усилий с стороны процессора чем простое сравнивание в условии двух величин. (Всё зависит от реализации движка js). Возможно в некоторых случаях, вызов метода будет быстрей чем сравнить в условии две величины (если внутри обработка if написана криво)

Comment: Между `key in obj` и `obj.hasOwnProperty('key')` есть разница. Второй не ищет унаследованные свойства.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Начну с различия оператора `in` и метода `hasOwnProperty`.

Оператор `in` ищет наличие ключей не только в самом объекте, но и в его прототипах.
А метод `hasOwnProperty` только в конкретном объекте.

```
const obj = {
  key: 'value',
};

console.log('key' in obj); // true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('key')); // true

console.log('toString' in obj); // true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('toString')); // false
```

Также стоит упомянуть тот факт, что если мы изменим значение ключа в исходном объекте на `undefined`, то оператор `in` все равно вернет `true`, что логично, так как свойство по-прежнему есть в объекте.

```
const obj = {
  key: undefined,
};

console.log('key' in obj); // true
```

C typeof есть один нюанс. Он нормально отработает, если искомого ключа нет в объекте. А если значение есть, но оно равно undefined, то мы получим не тот результат, который ожидали.

```
const obj = {
  key: undefined,
};

console.log(typeof obj['key2'] !== "undefined"); // false
console.log(typeof obj['key'] !== "undefined"); // false, ключа нет
```

Ну, а способ с `Object.keys` просто пройдется по массиву ключей и вернет `true`, если найдет искомый ключ. И опять же метод `keys` вернет ключи конкретного объекта, не затрагивая его прототипы.

```
class SomeObj {
  constructor(value) {
    this.key1 = value;
  }
}

SomeObj.prototype.key2 = 'other value';

const obj = new SomeObj('value');

console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ['key1']

for (key in obj) {
  console.log(key); // key1, key2
}
```

Короче говоря, лучше использовать способ, который не сравнивает значения и не создает массив для поиска в нем ключей. По крайней мере это семантически неправильно. А из оператора `in` и метода `hasOwnProperty` уже надо выбирать тот, который подходит для решения конкретной задачи.

Еще замечу, что при использовании метода hasOwnProperty линтер (eslint) может [ругаться](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) на его использование. Происходит это потому, что есть возможность перезаписи метода.